# Good book on solitons focusing mainly on analysis of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, soliton-theory

I have a good background in PDEs and functional analysis and I would like to learn more about solitons. The most popular references that I see pop up are Drazin and Kasman, but the first is a little less rigorous than I prefer and the second focuses on algebra, which is just not to my taste. Does anyone have a good reference for solitons from an analysis point of view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, many books on solitary waves are written from a physical perspective. From a mathematical physics or applied mathematics point of view, I would suggest these:

A.C. Newell: *Solitons in Mathematics and Physics*. SIAM, 1985. [books.google](https://books.google.com/books?id=jUDZHPXLNQMC) [doi:10.1137/1.9781611970227](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611970227)

A.-M. Wazwaz: *Partial Differential Equations and Solitary Waves Theory*. Springer, 2009. [books.google](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZnrjZZbrsgUC) [doi:10.1007/978-3-642-00251-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00251-9)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of books I found helpful were

*Solitons and the Inverse Scattering Transform*, by Ablowitz and Segur.

Slightly more focused on solitons in optical fibers:

*Mathematical Principles of Optical Fiber Communications*, by J. K. Shaw.